# Behavior of ObjectInputStream (Android) if no object is present

Tags: java, android, serialization, objectinputstream

I'm trying to make a fairly simple Android project and need to wrap my head around data storage on the platform. I found some code that seems to do something similar to what I want to do. However, I'm curious what the behavior is of the 'readObject' function if no object has yet been written to file. Will it return a null?

```
public final class InternalStorage{

private InternalStorage() {}

public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```

}

Comment: why don't you try this case and see what happens?

Comment: I should. I'm new to Android, don't know how to debug in it yet, don't want to do it yet, and want to know this behavior so I can think about solutions until I return to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will throw an `EOFException,` either in the constructor of `ObjectInputStream` if the file is zero length, or in `readObject()` if the object stream header has been written (i.e. the constructor of `ObjectOutputStream` has executed.)

> Will it return a null?

No. It will return a null if you *wrote* a null, e.g. with `writeObject(null),` or `writeObject(object)` where `object` is null, and not at any other time.